# Displaying date in Month DD,YYYY format

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display the date in below format

```
July 23, 2011 

SELECT REG_NO, FORMAT(DOB ,'YYYY/MM/DD') 
FROM Students ;
```

I tried below

```
SELECT REG_NO, FORMAT(DOB ,'MON DD,YYYY') 
FROM Students ;
```

It seems not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use **to_char**

The syntax is `to_char( value, [ format_mask ], [ nls_language ] )`

```
SELECT REG_NO, TO_CHAR(DOB ,'MONTH DD,YYYY') FROM Students ;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about trying this one:

```
SELECT REG_NO, to_char(DOB, 'FMMonth DD, YYYY') FROM Students;
```

[TO_CHAR()](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php)

Answer (score 1):

The correct SQL is

```
SELECT REG_NO, to_char(DOB, 'MONTH DD, YYYY') FROM Students;
```

DD: Day Of Month

MONTH: Full Month Name

MM: Numeric Month

MON: Abbreviated Month, ex. Jul

YYYY: 4-DIGIT Year

For more on ORACLE date-format [click here](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html)